# Visual Studio 2017 ASP Project cant publish db.lock being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to publish an ASP project but get the below error message:

Error       Copying file .vs###\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.vs###\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock failed. The process cannot access the file '.vs###\v15\Server\sqlite3\db.lock' because it is being used by another process.

The project uses MS SQL so have no idea what this db.lock is about :S

The project has worked fine for years and have never seen anything like this before, I've spent some time duckduckgoing around for answers but everything I've tried hasn't had any effect.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try adding the following into your publishing profile -

```
 <PropertyGroup>

    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>.vs</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>

  </PropertyGroup>
```

Publishing profile is the following file - profile.pubxml